# _base.scss and base.scss in compass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, compass-sass

My scss files are like so...

```
src/partials/_base.scss
src/base.scss
```

What will happen here? Will the _base.scss overwrite what's in base.scss? Or will they be merged? Or...what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first file will be evaluated, then the next one.
having the same filename shouldn't be a problem for compass/sass.